# ContentNote Load using Informatica Cloud

Tags: field-mapping, contentnote, contentdocumentlink

Background : 
We have lot of junk data from source for Lead object and the same is suggested to be concatenated and loaded to Notes.

Issue: 
We could load the Title and Content - For Titel - A default Value and For Content: The concatenated data from source. After that to link the ContentNote with the Lead object we came to know that ContentDocumentLink should be loaded - But we are left no where in mapping the fields - ContentDocumentId is Id from COntentNote but how we know what Lead.Id should be mapped to LinkedEntityId - How can i map the contentNotes back to my Lead Object?

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on exact same scenario,
Steps
1. Load ContentNote Data, Your file should have, LeadId , Title and Content (Don't map your lead ID for contentnote load).
2. Once you completed ContentNote load, Your success file should have contentNote Id and corresponding LeadId.
3. Use your success file for laod contentdocument link (ContentDocumentId=ContentNoteId, LinkedEntityID=leadId)

Let me know if you need help.

Thanks
Pradeep

Comment: Hi Pradeep thanks for the response. In ContentNote load, as you know, we can load only Content and Title fields and nothing else.  The success file can have ContentNote.Id, Content, Title fields only. So now how can i get the Lead.Id to map to LinkedEntityId ?

Comment: Your source file should have, LeadId in this case (basically linkedEntityid). While loading map Title and content fields (don't map lead id). once you complete the contentNote migration, your success file will have Leadid and content note id. Use this file to load contentDocumentLink data. You can make use of external id on lead as linkedentityId Let me know if you still need help.